# Python object not overwritten when reinitialized in the for loop

Tags: python, object, for-loop, initialization

So I have this class:

```
class SUSTAIN:

    def __init__(self, r, beta, d, threshold, learn):

        self.clusters = []
        self.activations = []
        self.connections = []
        self.catunitacts = []
        self.coutputs = []

        self.maxValue = 0.0
        self.minValue = 0.0

    def stimulate(self, item, env):
        #code
        return [response, probofcorrect, outputprobs, self.catunitacts, self.activations, self.distances]

    def learn(self, item, env):
        #code
        return [self.LAMBDAS, self.connections, self.clusters, int(maskclus[3][1]), accuracy, len(self.clusters)]
```

and I want to initialize an object from it 100 times in the following function:

```
def testing(data):
    subjectdata = []
    subjectdata2 = []
    #loop1
    for i in range(100):
        model = SUSTAIN(r = 0.0, beta = 5.386305, d = 5.0,  
            threshold = 0.89, learn = 0.09361126)
        #loop2
        for k in range(4):
            #loop3
            for j in trainingblock:
                trialn = int(floor(j[0][1]))
                [res, prob, outunits, outacts, act, dist] = model.stimulate(j, env)
                [lambdas, clus, conn, response, accuracy, nclus] = model.learn(j, env)
                trialdata = [response, accuracy, nclus]
                subjectdata.append(trialdata)
        #loop4
        for k in dataitems:
            trialn = int(floor(k[0][1]))
            [res, prob, outunits, outacts, act, dist] = model.stimulate(k, env)
            [lambdas,  clus,  conn,  response,  n] = model.learn(k, env)
            trialdata = [trialn, response, n]
            subjectdata2.append(trialdata)
    write_file("training", directory1, subjectdata, ',')
    write_file("generalization", directory2, subjectdata2, ',')
```

For some strange reason, loop4 in the function keeps influencing the results of the loop2 although they are absolutely independent of each other and a new instance is initialized everytime in loop1. It is like python remembers the object and does not delete it. I know that loop2 influences the results of loop4 and that is intentionally but the opposite is just weird.

Comment: Please reduce your code example down to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. By doing that, you might even solve the problem yourself. If you don't solve the problem, it will make it much easier for others to focus on the important parts.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `model` in loop2 and loop4. This model contains lists

```
    self.clusters = []
    self.activations = []
    self.connections = []
    self.catunitacts = []
    self.coutputs = []
```

which are also returned by `stimulate` and `learn`. There is only one instance of each of this lists for each model. Changing the contents of one of these lists anywhere, changes it everywhere.

Comment: yes but this is not the problem. The problem is when I reinitialize the model again in loop1, the newly initialized model in loop2 behaves like it is the same instance that was previously initialized not a new one. I tried setting the model to an empty string at the end of loop1 but nothing changed.

Comment: I am doing normal array operations and assigning values to the parameters of the model. Env is just a masking array that I use in the functions.

Comment: there's not enough to replicate this.  What happens when you del(model)?